# MacBook M1 Big Sur crashes every time when I open "About This Mac -> Storage -> Manage"

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, data-synchronization, crash, big-sur

**Background:** I'm using a MacBook Pro with M1 chip and Big Sur V11.1 (got it last month). One thing really annoys me is that when I connect my iphone, sync starts automatically and it takes up 20GB to when all iphone files are backed up.

**Issue:** So I wanted to delete the sync files using "Reduce Clutter" in "About This Mac -> Storage". It worked fine for two weeks after I purchased the MacBook, but recently it starts to crash every time when I open "About This Mac -> Storage -> Manage" and I wasn't even able to get the time to click "Review Files" under "Manage". I tried to restart the system but had no luck at all. See screenshots below for crash report.

[image: screenshot1]

[image: screenshot2]

**Help:** Does anyone else encounter the same issue? How to resolve it? Is there a way (say, command line) to delete synced iphone files without clicking "About This Mac -> Storage"?

"Manage-> Review Files" is a really convenient way to view and remove redundant files to save storage. It would be great if there is a way to revive that functionality if possible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

iOS installer are located in

```
~/Library/iTunes
```

and you need to find your device's folder

iOS backups are located in

```
~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup
```

or you can select iOS device via side bar, select General tab and then Manage backups
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's the fold I need. Still, the crash issue remains, which is very annoying.